# Span of Vectors Equals "0"

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible for the span of two or more vectors in the $\mathbb{R}$ to be $\vec{0}$? I assume that it should be if each vector is the zero vector but is that allowed?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be ?

Comment: All the zero vectors might be considered to be the same vector.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, let's be clear, a span of vectors can never be $0$ in any case, because a span of vectors is a **set**, not a vector. We can, however, ask when a span of vectors is $\{\vec 0\}$, which is what I assume you wanted to ask.

---

Since the span of a set of vectors always includes at least those two vectors, the only way for a span of a set of vectors to be $\{\vec 0\}$ is if the set of vectors includes at most one vector, the zero vector.

This means that **NO**, the span of two or more vectors cannot be $0$. If you have a set $S$ of at least two vectors, then at least one of them is not $0$, let's call it $v\in S$. Therefore, $\vec 0\neq v\in\mathrm{span}(S)$ and therefore, $\mathrm{span}(S)\neq \{\vec0\}$.

Comment: So, according to your comment, when we say that we have $span(\vec{v_{1}}, \vec{v_{2}})$, we are also saying that the vectors $\vec{v_{1}}$ and $\vec{v_{2}}$ are distinct?

Comment: @randomMathTime Well... they are if you want to claim that $span(v_1,v_2)$ is a span of **two** vectors. If $v_1=v_2$, then $span(v_1, v_2)$ is a span of **one** vector. I mean, if I have a party and invite you and you, I can't honestly claim I invited two people, can I?

Comment: Alright, thanks!